# Обработка ошибок ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

На страницу, через jqery ajax подгружается js:

```
   $.ajax({
     url: Path,
     dataType: "script",
     error: function (xhr) {
       onsole.log('Ошибка: ' xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText);
     }
    });
```

Если, допустим, файла не существует, через функцию в error, выводится ошибка в лог.
Но в лог дополнительно выходит ошибка загрузки файла.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал обернуть запрос в try {} catch(e){} все равно ошибка выводится в лог.
Как убрать эту ошибку и вместо нее выполнить свой код?

Comment: `onsole.log` - это так же написано в исходнике? Или магия копипастинга?

Comment: Это как пример, вместо этого, естественно, будет другой код

Comment: Не зажал 'c', случайно